# Passing double between Activities

Tags: android

I have a problem with passing double between activities. It doesn't display in the second activity. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in Advance

**OnBindViewHolder**

```
 holder.country_all.setText(String.valueOf(pozycja.getPopulation()));
```

**OnClick**

```
   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, Details.class);

   ...
    mIntent.putExtra("Country_Population",pozycja.getPopulation());
    context.startActivity(mIntent);

        }
    });
```

**Second Activity**

```
Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  if (mBundle!= null){
...
mCountry_Population.setText(mBundle.getString("Country_Population"));
}
```

Comment: does it open second activity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `getPopulation()` returns a `double`, then you need to call `getDoubleExtra()` on the `Intent` (instead of `getString()` on the `Bundle`):

```
mCountry_Population
    .setText(String.valueOf(getIntent()
            .getDoubleExtra("Country_Population", 0)));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but now it's 0 everywhere instead of correct value

Comment: @smitzervojtech Well if the value is correct and you put it in the bundle, retrieving it with the same key and it still returns the default value, then you alter the bundle somewhere. Are you sure getPopulation() returns a double and not an int or a long?